# excenter formula using vectors

Tags: geometry

How do i derive the excenter formula using  vectors in a triangle? I solved the other problem that I have [previously posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4279851) and got that

$$\overrightarrow{OE}\;=\;\frac{c}{b-c}\,\overrightarrow{OC}-\frac{b}{b-c}\,\overrightarrow{OB}$$
But can I use this in some way to find the formula for the excenter?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: If you solved [your previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4279851/409), then you should post your solution as an answer (and accept it) so that people reading it don't think you still need help.

Comment: The excenter on side $AB$ (let's call it $J_C$) lies on the line $AE$, so $\overrightarrow{OJ_C} = \lambda \overrightarrow{OE} + (1-\lambda)\overrightarrow{OA}$ for some number $\lambda$. Reverse the role of $AB$ and let $E'$ be the intersection of $AC$ with exterior angle bisector of $B$. You have a similar formula for $\overrightarrow{OE'}$ and another $\lambda'$ such that $\overrightarrow{OJ_C} = \lambda' \overrightarrow{OE'} + (1-\lambda')\overrightarrow{OB}$. Just compare coefficeints of these two formulae of $\overrightarrow{OJ_C}$.